# How to get data in ranges?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to SQL and the below query is to calculate the count of vehicles which have travelled  between 0 to 100 km within a time period.

```
select  1 as "1 - 100",count (*) from (
SELECT extract (day from start_time) as day ,place, vehicle_id,sum(distance_two_points) as distance
FROM public.datatable where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
and place=1 group by day, place ,veh_id
order by day,place,veh_id ) as A where distance >0 and distance<100
```

Here distance_two_points shows the distance in one trip and a vehicle will have more than a trip.So I take the sum of distance_two_points  for each vehicle_id which gives the total distance travelled by the vehicle.

The subquery

```
SELECT extract (day from start_time) as day ,place, vehicle_id,sum(distance_two_points) as distance
FROM public.datatable where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
and place=1 group by day, place ,veh_id
order by day,place,veh_id
```

will return all the vehicle's total distance travelled and then I filter by

```
distance >0 and distance<100
```

Instead of one filtering I want to categorize as the following:

```
     range     count
     ______    ______
     1-100      17
     100-200    30
     300-400    40
     400-500    39
     500-600    36
```

Instead of combining five queries is there a method to get the above results? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your query is really confusing.  You have `sum(points) as length` and then use `length` in the `where` clause.  Those are different `length`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the query now it seems to be more clearer than before

Comment: Sorry, but it is more confusing than before...

Comment: @ Roman Tkachuk Let me explain I want to have the count of vehicles which travels in the distance range,My above query gives that 17 vehicles are there which travels between 1-100 km.Likewise I would like to have for the whole range(total 5 ranges).

Comment: @RomanTkachuk I updated the question.I hope now it should be clear.

Comment: Can you give some table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` for the `group by` key.  You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN points >= 0 AND points <= 100 THEN '1-100'
             WHEN points <= 200 THEN '101-200'
             WHEN points <= 300 THEN '201-300'
             WHEN points <= 400 THEN '301-400'
             WHEN points <= 500 THEN '401-500'
             WHEN points <= 600 THEN '501-600'
        END) as range,
       COUNT(*) as length
FROM public.datatable 
WHERE start_time >= '2015-09-05' and start_time < '2015-09-06' and
      place = 1 and length>=0 and length<=100 and place=1 
GROUP BY range
ORDER BY MIN(points);
```

Comment: If `points` can be negative, all cases need to start with (at least) `points >= 0 AND ...` -- if it cannot, neither of the cases requires that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function do determine the text:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION points_diff(int)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql

AS $function$

select
        a::text||'-'||(a+99)::text
from
        generate_series(1,$1+100,100) a
where
        $1 between a and a+99;

$function$

;
```

Comment: That is a lot of combination, which this will generate (before the `WHERE` filter). Wouldn't it be simpler if you just say `$1 between a and a + 99`?

Comment: I edited the question please check the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH x AS (
     SELECT extract (day from start_time) as day,
            place,
            vehicle_id,
            sum(distance_two_points) as distance
       FROM public.datatable
      where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00'
        and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
        and place=1
   group by day, place ,veh_id
), z AS (
     SELECT ((distance - 1) / 100)::int8 AS range,
            count (*)
       FROM x
   GROUP BY 1
)
  SELECT (range * 100 + 1)::text || '-' || ((range + 1) * 100),
         count
    FROM z
ORDER BY range
```

Comment: I edited the question please change the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

The Case works fine.@Gordon Linoff suggested I have to use case and it works like a charm.Hope it helps anyone

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN distance >= 0 AND distance< 10000 THEN '0-10'
                WHEN distance >= 10000 AND distance < 20000  THEN '10-20'
                WHEN distance >= 20000 AND distance <30000 THEN '20-30'
                 WHEN distance >= 30000 AND distance < 40000 THEN '30-40'
                 WHEN distance >= 40000 AND distance < 50000 THEN '40-50'
                   WHEN distance >= 50000 AND distance < 60000  THEN '50-60'
                WHEN distance >= 60000 AND distance <70000 THEN '60-70'
                 WHEN distance >= 70000 AND distance < 80000 THEN '70-80'
                 WHEN distance >= 80000 AND distance < 100000 THEN '80-90'
                 WHEN distance >=90000 THEN 'above 100' 
            END) as range,count(*) as taxi_count
            from (



          SELECT extract (day from start_time) as day, place,taxi_num_id,sum(distance_two_points) as distance
    FROM public.datatable where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' and place=1
      group by day,veh_id,place
    order by day,veh_id 



)  as A group by range  order by range
```

Answer (score -2):

```
where datediff (d,startdate, enddate) <= 100 
and startdate between startdate and enddate
```

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx

Comment: this is not about SQL Server but PostgreSQL